# Can't fix an user account in Mavericks (frozen)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, user-account

My regular user account on my Macbook Pro running Mavericks froze and I had to shut down the computer with the power button, but every time I restart the computer and login my user account it freezes and doesn't respond to any command. It stays with the spinning beachball and does not respond to any menu (not even force quit). 
I have already tried safe boot, restart in recovery mode, checked the hard disk and permissions with disk utility and still have the same problem: can't use any programme on my user account. When logging with other user account the computer seems to work fine. Any thoughts on how to fix it? I need it fixed asap!!

Comment: It looks like you know what you doing, so just a question: did you try to reset that users ACL's?

Comment: Are any applications starting automatically when you log in?  One of those apps might be causing the hung state.

Answer (score 1):

First step I would recommend is to restore the users account permissions also called ACL's. The ACL's get messed up sometimes leading to kind of problems you are having.

To do that use the following steps:

1. Hold Command-R during restart.
2. Select Terminal and run `resetpassword`.
3. Select the account in question.
4. **Do not** reset the password.

   Instead click on the **Reset Home Folder Permissions and ACLs** at the bottom right.